# unrar a password protected archive in batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to use a batch file to automatically extract files from a password protected rar archive.
I tried this code:

```
@echo off
UNRAR E -INUL -P ne2020 "%~dp0program.rar"
pause
```

but the output that the cmd window that showed to me tells me that unrar aren't an internal/external command.
how to fix that?

Comment: Try giving it the full path to where the UNRAR.exe is.

Comment: Do you have Winrar installed?

Comment: Another thing other then full path; the password should be like this `-pne2020` without space

Comment: @Squashman yes it's installed

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try with this batch file :

```bat
@echo off
Title Unzip Winrar Files in command line
color 0A
Mode con cols=75 lines=10
Set "file=%~dp0program.rar"
set "RAR_Password=ne2020"
Set Log=%~n0_UnzipLog.txt
for %%i in ("%file%") do ( set "DEST=%~dp0%%~ni" )
set strProgramFiles=%ProgramFiles%
if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" set strProgramFiles=%ProgramFiles(x86)%
Set Unrar="%strProgramFiles%\WinRAR\UnRar.exe"
If not exist "%DEST%" MD "%DEST%"
If Exist %Unrar% ( Goto :Unrar ) else ( Goto :Fail )

:Unrar
%UNRAR% E -inul -y -p%RAR_Password% "%file%" "%DEST%">nul 2>&1
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" EQU "0" ( GOTO Succes ) Else ( Goto Fail )

:Succes
Echo(
Echo All Files are unzipped succesfuly ! in "%DEST%" 
Echo All Files are unzipped succesfuly ! in "%DEST%"  > "%Log%"
Start "" /MAX "%Log%"
Timeout /T 3 /nobreak>nul
Exit /b

:Fail
Color 0C
Echo(
echo There was an error ! 
echo There was an error !  > "%Log%"
Start /MAX "" "%Log%
Timeout /T 3 /nobreak>nul
```

Comment: @man_s_our What did you modified in this code exactly ? did you check your password it is correct ? and the file to be extracted too ?

Comment: I didn't modify anything

Comment: the password and rar path was correct. but I needed to put unrar.exe in the same dir or use cd command

Answer (score 0):

after I checked the comments I found the answers.
there is 2 ways.
1st:

putting unrar.exe file in the same directory with the batch file

2nd:
adding this line:

```
cd C:\Program Files\WinRAR\
```

without forgetting to not to separate between -p and the password.